# Any In App Document (pdf, docx, xslx) viewer library module available for react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have been trying to open documents like (`pdf`, `docx`, `xslx`) file into (inside the app, not in any other installed app) my `react-native` application. From research I got some `PDF` viewer only that will be used to open pdf inside the app but not the other two types `DOCx` and `XSLx`.

I got some `doc-viewer` also, that full fill some of my requirement that it can be used to open document of all three of it's type but in other installed app not inside my `react-native` app.

I have created demo projects for these and checked but non of it help me with my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the developers,
We can use `WebView` from 'react-native-webview' module to display docs from URL. 
I have done as below,

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=${YOUR_URL}`}}
    startInLoadingState={true} />
```

Important part is `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=${}` which will display your doc from URL.

Comment: is it working now ?
I am not able to load document file url on WebView inside app

Comment: using aws URL its not working it shows no preview available attaching above link

Comment: I am trying to load aws s3 ppt, xls and doc URL but it didn't work with above one